# SQL Subquery returned more than 1 value when adding Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I tried creating procedure in SQL Server so that I can pass the `users_id` value to another table.

However, when filling in data asp.net returns an error that subquery returned more than 1 value. Here is my procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[insert_rent]
    @comment_info NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @booth_size NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @customer_type NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @booth_type NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @customer_email TEXT,
    @customer_mobile TEXT
AS
    DECLARE @Users_Id INT 

    IF EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM Users)
    BEGIN
        SET @Users_Id = (SELECT Id FROM Users)

        INSERT INTO Rent (rent_comments, booth_size, customer_type, booth_type, customer_email, customer_mobile, Users_id) 
        VALUES (@comment_info, @booth_size, @customer_type, @booth_type, @customer_email, @customer_mobile, @Users_Id)
    END
```

Here is my code:

```
String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BoothsConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert_rent", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    con.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@comment_info", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = comment_input.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@booth_size", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = size_dropwdown.SelectedValue.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@customer_type", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = customer_type_dropdown.SelectedValue.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@booth_type", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = booth_type_dropdown.SelectedValue.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@customer_email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = customer_email.Value;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@customer_mobile", SqlDbType.NText).Value = customer_mobilenumber.Value;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I'm fairly sure there is something wrong with my procedure.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: The one built into visual studio

Comment: `set @Users_Id = (select Id from Users)` -- here is the problem

Comment: You have many id's coming through for each row insert

Comment: Ah, i see. How can i specify that i want to take the if of currently logged in user. I think i should use where statement, but how do i do it?

Comment: `select Id from Users` will return every id of every user in the `users` table. You are attempting to set variable `@user_id` to every id in that table, and that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why not pass in the UserID as another parameter? Unless you have a different database user for every user in your application that is pretty much what you need to do.

Comment: How could you query your `users` table with information in your application to that user's `id` from this table. We don't know your application and we don't know you table's data/schema so we can't really help with that. Something like `SELECT id FROM users WHERE user_email = @customer_email`... or something like that.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for the existance of any Id in `Users`.

```
if exists(select Id from Users)
```

This will always be true, as long as there is at least one row in your table.

In the next step you try to set a variable to a value:

```
set @Users_Id = (select Id from Users)
```

But without a fitting `WHERE` you will get all Ids your table `Users` contains.

Using a sub-select to set a variable demands for a **scalar** result.